# Criação de tabelas através de div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, css3

Gostaria de criar uma estrutura de tabelas que possam ter uma quantidade variável de colunas, exemplo, uma hora possa ser que tenha somente 3 colunas e em outro momento pode ter 5 ou 6 colunas, esse número não é limitado, essas quantidade de colunas não irá mudar uma vez depois depois que a tela seja carregada.

Estou com problemas para fazer o alinhamentos delas e deixar o CSS de forma que se adapte bem a quantidade de colunas que venha ter, por exemplo, *Bosque das Flores* e *Cond Grego*, tem que está abaixo da coluna Condominio e assim por diante.

Segue meu código abaixo:

```css
.content-body {
    display: table-cell;
    position: relative;
    vertical-align: top;
    padding: 40px;
}
    .rowCustom {
        display: -moz-flex;
        display: -webkit-flex;
        display:            flex;
        -webkit-flex-direction:     row;
        -moz-flex-direction:     row;
        flex-direction:     row;
        display:            -webkit-flex;
        display:            -moz-flex;
        table-layout:       fixed;
        width:              95%;
        margin:             0 auto;
        white-space:        nowrap;
      }
      
      .rowCustom div {
        -webkit-flex: 1 1 auto;
        -moz-flex: 1 1 auto;
        flex: 1 1 auto;
        display:            inline-block;
      }

      .column {
        margin:             0 auto;
        padding:            5px;
        text-align:         center;
      }

    .item{  
        display: inline-block;  
        border: 1px solid #ccc;  
        padding: 5px 10px;  
        text-decoration: none;  
        color: #666;      
        font-family: 'Open Sans',sans-serif;  
        font-size: 14px;  
        font-weight :600;  
        border-radius: 5px;  
        -webkit-border-radius: 5px;  
        -moz-border-radius: 5px;  
    }
```

```html
<link href="https://rawgit.com/twbs/bootstrap/master/dist/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<section role="main" class="content-body">    
    <div class="rowCustom">
        <div class="column">
            Condominio
        </div>
        <div class="column">
            Predio
        </div>
        <div class="column">
            Andar
        </div>
        <div class="column">
            Apartamento
        </div>
        <div class="column">
            Comodo
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="rowCustom">
        <div class="column">
            <div class="item">Bosque das flores</div> 
        </div>
        <div class="column">
        </div>
        <div class="column">
        </div>
        <div class="column">
        </div>
        <div class="column">
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="rowCustom">
        <div class="column">
        </div>
        <div class="column">
            <div class="item">Orquidea</div>       
        </div>
        <div class="column">
        </div>
        <div class="column">
        </div>
        <div class="column">
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="rowCustom">
        <div class="column">
        </div>
        <div class="column">            
        </div>
        <div class="column">
        <div class="item">1º Andar</div> 
        </div>
        <div class="column">
        </div>
        <div class="column">
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="rowCustom">
        <div class="column">
        </div>
        <div class="column">
        </div>
        <div class="column">
            <div class="item">2º Andar</div> 
        </div>
        <div class="column">
        </div>
        <div class="column">
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="rowCustom">
        <div class="column">
        </div>
        <div class="column">
            <div class="item">Rosa</div> 
        </div>
        <div class="column">
        </div>
        <div class="column">
        </div>
        <div class="column">
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="rowCustom">
        <div class="column">
            <div class="item">Cond Grego</div> 
        </div>
        <div class="column">
        </div>
        <div class="column">
        </div>
        <div class="column">
        </div>
        <div class="column">
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="rowCustom">
        <div class="column">
        </div>
        <div class="column">
            <div class="item">Apolo</div> 
        </div>
        <div class="column">
        </div>
        <div class="column">
        </div>
        <div class="column">
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

Segue o [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jeferson07/nppbwytz/2/)

Minha estrutura funciona da seguinte maneira, na primeira linha estão as colunas, e nas linhas seguintes são os valores, somente uma das colunas será preenchida em cada linha, cada uma dessas linhas podem ter filhos, que serão acrescentados na linha logo abaixo e na coluna subsequente, o principal problema está no alinhamento do conteúdos das linhas com os das colunas.

Se possível, seria bom que existisse uma linha ligando as linhas com seus respectivos filhos, ex: Um linha ligando *Bosque das Flores* a *Orquidea* e a *Rosa*, outra ligando *Orquidea* a *1º andar* e a *2º andar* e assim sucessivamente.

Segue uma imagem, feita em paint, de como espero que fique mais ou menos.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Posso perguntar pq não usar uma tabela?

Comment: @Aline porque queria algo parecido com uma treeview e não sei se com tables isso ficaria muito bom, por isso tive a ideia de usar div

Comment: Testou o js? Aqui funcionou bacana.

Answer (score 1):

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
        $(".column").css("width", $("#geral").outerWidth() / $(".content-body>.rowCustom:first>div").length);
    });
```

Se for usar jquery, não esqueça a referência da lib.

CSS:

```
.column {
        margin: 0 auto;
        padding: 5px;
        text-align: center;
        border:1px solid #cecece;
    }
```

HTML:

```
<div id="geral">
    <link href="https://rawgit.com/twbs/bootstrap/master/dist/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <section role="main" class="content-body">
        <div class="rowCustom">
            <div class="column">
                Condominio
            </div>
            <div class="column">
                Predio
            </div>
            <div class="column">
                Andar
            </div>
            <div class="column">
                Apartamento
            </div>
            <div class="column">
                Comodo
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="rowCustom">
            <div class="column">
                <div class="item">Bosque das flores</div>
            </div>
            <div class="column">
            </div>
            <div class="column">
            </div>
            <div class="column">
            </div>
            <div class="column">
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="rowCustom">
            <div class="column">
            </div>
            <div class="column">
                <div class="item">Orquidea</div>
            </div>
            <div class="column">
            </div>
            <div class="column">
            </div>
            <div class="column">
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="rowCustom">
            <div class="column">
            </div>
            <div class="column">
            </div>
            <div class="column">
                <div class="item">1º Andar</div>
            </div>
            <div class="column">
            </div>
            <div class="column">
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="rowCustom">
            <div class="column">
            </div>
            <div class="column">
            </div>
            <div class="column">
                <div class="item">2º Andar</div>
            </div>
            <div class="column">
            </div>
            <div class="column">
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="rowCustom">
            <div class="column">
            </div>
            <div class="column">
                <div class="item">Rosa</div>
            </div>
            <div class="column">
            </div>
            <div class="column">
            </div>
            <div class="column">
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="rowCustom">
            <div class="column">
                <div class="item">Cond Grego</div>
            </div>
            <div class="column">
            </div>
            <div class="column">
            </div>
            <div class="column">
            </div>
            <div class="column">
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="rowCustom">
            <div class="column">
            </div>
            <div class="column">
                <div class="item">Apolo</div>
            </div>
            <div class="column">
            </div>
            <div class="column">
            </div>
            <div class="column">
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
</div>
```

Comment: No caso quem seria `$("#geral")`, eu não tenho esse id dentro do meu HTML

Comment: Desculpe, é  uma div externa a section. só uma div com esse id. Que tem largura em 100%. Sacou?

Comment: O alinhamento ficou como eu queria, muito obrigado, agora você saberia também como fazer as linhas ligando os elementos conforme a img que eu coloquei?

Comment: Não consigo ver a imagem. Bloqueado o dominio aqui. =x As linhas da "tabela" eu adicionei ali no CSS. (=

Comment: As linhas q eu me referi não são as bordas, preciso de linha ligando com seus respectivos filhos, ex: Um linha ligando Bosque das Flores a Orquidea e a Rosa, outra ligando Orquidea a 1º andar e a 2º andar e assim sucessivamente. Segue o link da img em base64 https://pastebin.com/j1SPb5TU , caso vc queria ver

Comment: Acho que essa não vou conseguir te ajudar pq eu precisaria ver o q tu espera e não vai rolar agora. =T